# SSRS - Implementing a parameter constraint

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

On my report I have two parameters.
One is for the selection of an order number from a list (dropdown list) and the other is for typing an order number. The idea is to have the end-user either select the order number or type it, not both...
Is there a way I could empty the textbox when a list item was selected and vice versa, i.e. selecting an empty value from the dropdown list once an order number has been typed? I thought about using code but it would be impossible to determine which of the two parameters to use once the "view report" button has been pressed.

Any other approaches to this situation are very welcome.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Define the parameters**

Let's assume the first parameter that allows the user to enter the order number is called *typed_value* and the second parameter that allows the user to select an item from the list is called *list_value*.

**Prevent list from being used if value is typed in**

Add the following to the where clause of the query that populates the list_value

```
WHERE @typed_value IS NULL
```

This will prevent any records from being returned when the typed_value is not NULL, blocking the customer from selecting an order from the list if they have already typed in an order.

**Update list_value with typed_value**

The above code will only remove the list items, but to get the list to populate with the typed value add this union to the query that populates the list_value

```
UNION SELECT @typed_value WHERE @typed_value IS NOT NULL
```

If the user leaves the typed_value NULL then they can select any value from the list_value.  If the user types in a value, the list will automatically be replaced with their typed_value.

**Which value to use?**

You can power your report filter off of the list_value and ignore the typed_value because if the user enters any value in typed_value, the list_value will be updated to the typed_value.

**Smooth out the UX**

Make sure the parameter typed_value allows null value.  It may be a good idea to set the default value of typed_value to NULL so that the user can see the list values when the report first loads.

Also setting the default value of the list_value to @typed_value will automatically set the list_value to whatever value a customer types in.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! A quick follow up question: is there a way to combine the two? i.e. select a value from the list or type a value in the same 'box'.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that in the default SSRS report dispaly.  However if you are serving up the SSRS reports using the web forms report viewer you can set your parameter to be hidden and then setup your own UI for passing in that parameter value.